# Best way to render and save Images

Tags: php, web-applications, canvas, svg, rendering

I am working on a project that consists of a online store, to sell Printed Circuit Boards.
But the hole system will be automated, and will be able to view online the Gerber files (Gerber are the files that has the machine code for the pcb).

I need to choose the best way to "output" this file uploaded by the user, to the webpage. Only for viewing the PCB before buying.

I have done the entire PHP code to process the Gerber, but, I can't decide if the file will be proccesed, and then:

- I will save as a PNG file (rendering will be done with the PHP image library {that is a shit}), and if the user zoom, or do anything, it will not be perfect... (I would need to render in a high resolutiong, and would take a lot of space, and also time to load)
- Render as an SVG file (Vector file), and show on the HTML as an mbeded element (Does it work on all new browsers? Is it slow to proccess?), The SVG file are awsome in terms of drawing lines...
- And the last but not least way to doit, is to create a list of JavaScript commands, that draws on a Canvas Element (I have already implemented this, and works really good, but I don't like to think, that I'm actualy 'rendering' to a code...)

Anyway, what do you think I should use, and if I didn't tought in another way of doing it, please tell me!

Here is an example of the output as Canvas (With the source being a JavaScript function object, that has many drawLine commands):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm opting for SVG file, even if it's slower than `canvas`, but considering that won't be real time drawing process in terms of user interaction with the drawing object it's a good choice. SVG's are actually vectors, hence the images won't be crispy on large images. There are some quite good libraries out there which are working with svg-s like:

http://processingjs.org

http://d3js.org/

http://fabricjs.com/

http://raphaeljs.com/

I think d3 is one of the best. I definitely wont' recommend PHP image library.

Comment: I will use SVG. Do you think that rendering SVG with diferent sizes on the Browser cost a lot of process, and will be too slow?

Comment: You need to consider the image size when you are working with svg. Because the SVG is a vector graphics for large image sizes it may slow down the rendering process quite a bit.